# How to avoid "Fragment not attached to activity" in a screen workflow

Tags: android

I have a situation where one of the possible workflows of screens in the app could be like this:

`Home screen > Screen 1 > Dialog 1 > Dialog 2`

In that last Dialog, when the user clicks on the OK button it triggers an asynchronous API call. When that call completes, I need the dialog to dismiss and go back to the home screen as well as show a toast. This is what I have (`WebCall` is just a wrapper for the API which has a callback for successful calls):

```
// This is within the Dialog1 class

        final FragmentActivity context = getActivity(); //is this even safe to do?
        if(context == null) {
            return;
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context) // this is Dialog 2
                .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                .setMessage("Some Message")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        WebCall task = new WebCall(getContext());
                        task.setOnCompleteListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int code, String response) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Some message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        task.execute();
                        dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

The toast etc works all fine. If I **don't** put that `Intent` to go back to home, the app falls back to `Screen 1` - which makes sense, `Dialog 1` has already been dismissed by virtue of the fact that the user clicked on "OK" on that one, which lead to `Dialog 2`. However I want this to go back to `HomeScreen`.

So I put that `Intent` in. I don't care about retaining history, hence the `setFlags` (there is no "back" from the home screen). However I get the following error. I'm aware of `isAdded` method, however I need the workflow to go back to the home screen regardless of what happens. Any help would be great.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: <mypackage>, PID: 15719
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MessageDialog{6e99d7c} not attached to Activity
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1082)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1073)
        at <mypackage>.dialog.DeferPaymentDialog$5$1.onSuccess(MessageDialog.java:211)
        at <mypackage>.webservice.WebCall.onPostExecute(WebServiceTask.java:179)
        at <mypackage>.webservice.WebCall.onPostExecute(WebServiceTask.java:47)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you use DialogFragment as **Screen1**. After invocation *dismissAllowingStateLoss()* your dialog is to be detached from Activity. At the same time your background task is executed and at the moment it is finished dialog is dismissed. To resolve this issue you can use

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Additional thoughts:

Even though it will fix this issue you should reconsider the general structure since the background task overlives your fragment. So either invoke this task from the activity and just manually hide dialogs after it is task is finished.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Unfortunately I don't have much choice... the flow is dependant on a series of tasks completing

Comment: You need to check `isAdded` as well for extra careful